# Program stops - move array to function | C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have 2 classes.
First Class - **Midgam** - The constructor has the following line:

```
midgam = new Vector[20];
```

The second class - **Vector** - where I create an array named array.

The program works great just that I have a little problem.

At the end of the program I try to print in alphabetical order, I use the BubbleSort sorting. The sorting works fine but something in the Swap function stops.

This is how it looks:

```
void Midgam::Swap(Vector *xp, Vector *yp) {
    Vector temp = *xp;
    cout << temp.getName() << endl;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void Midgam::bubbleSort() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < iterator - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < iterator - i - 1; j++) {
            if (midgam[j].getName().compare(midgam[j+1].getName()) > 0) {
                Swap(&midgam[j], &midgam[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I work with Visual Studio, the program stops and the program shows me the following code snippet in the Vector class:

```
Vector::~Vector() {
if (array)
        delete[] array;
}
```

full definitions of **Midgam**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef MIDGAM_H_
#define MIDGAM_H_

class Midgam {
private:
    int boxNum;
    int maxParties;
    int iterator;
    Vector *midgam;
public:
    Midgam(int num_of_boxes, int num_of_parties);
    virtual ~Midgam();
    void Start();
    void Menurmal();
    void SumOfEzor();
    double SumOfParty(string name);
    int SumAllVotes();
    void AddParty();
    void Swap(Vector *xp, Vector *yp);
    void bubbleSort();
    void Histograma();
    void PrintStars(int num);
    int FindPartyByName(string party);
    void PrintAll();
};

#endif /* MIDGAM_H_ */
```

full definitions of **Vector**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef VECTOR_H_
#define VECTOR_H_

class Vector {
private:
    string name;
    int size;
    unsigned int *array;
    bool Bool;
public:
    Vector(string name, int size);
    Vector();
    Vector & operator=(const Vector &);
    virtual ~Vector();
    bool StringToArray(string str);
    bool getBool();
    string getName();
    unsigned int getAddress();
    int getSize();
    unsigned int getValueFromArray(int index);
    double sumOfArray();
    void PrintArray();
};

#endif /* VECTOR_H_ */
```

Does anyone know why it does not work? Thank you

Comment: Please provide full definitions of those classes. The Visual studio usually stops when the pointer is invalid and also shows a message. But because `array` is not mentioned anywhere in the snippets you provided, I cannot say more. My guess is that your copy constructor does shallow copy and the `temp` variable in the swap destroyes `xp`'s array.

Comment: Please provide the information requested by Quimby in the shaope of a [mcve]. (@Quimby, try writing `[mcve]` in a comment like yours.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for the advice I did not know that you didn't have to include the link and was too lazy to search for it. Also I thought that stating directly what is needed might have better chance of success :)

Comment: @Quimby I have updated the definitions.

Comment: I spy a violation of the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). `Vector` doesn't have a copy constructor, so the implicitly defined one is used. When a vector is constructed from another, both end up pointing to the same `array`. Then in destructor, each one tries to destroy it. Your program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of double destruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Vector` lacks a proper copy constructor.

```
Vector temp = *xp;
//NOT EQUAL TO:
//Vector temp;
//temp=*xp;
```

The above statement won't call `operator=(const Vector &)` even though there's an equal sign. The following line is correct and equivalent:

```
Vector temp(*xp);
```

The reason is that this is a copy **initialization** - `temp` is created and so a constructor must be called - in particular the copy constructor `Vector(const Vector &)`. Which you did not explicitly declared and so a default one was used.

Then a shallow copy is made, `temp` and `*xp` then share the same array and when both their destructors get called the second one will try to delete already deleted memory - undefined behavior which triggers Visual Studio's debugger (at least in debug mode).

The solution is to do a proper deep copy - create a new array and copy its contents:

```
#include <algorithm> #Contains std::copy_n
Vector::Vector(const Vector& other)
{
    name=other.name;
    size=other.size;
    //Creates a new array
    array= new unsigned int[size];
    //Copies the array contents
    std::copy_n(other.array,size,array);
    Boo=other.Bool;
}
```

Also this is a prime example of why not to use raw memory. I get that you are implementing custom vector and don't want to use `std::vector` for the `array` but at least use `std::unique_ptr`. If you would have just done that you wouldn't have to ask this question in the first place as the compiler would have complained and the debugger wouldn't have to do the compiler's job.

Comment: @Oz1988 Added the copy constructor :)